# how to parse xml file in C language on linux

Tags: c, xml

I'm going to make a weather program, so I need to parse an XML file.

I've installed a libxml(in fact, it was installed)

However, I don't know how to parse a number.

Here is part of my XML code:

```
<tmx>-999.0</tmx>
<tmn>-999.0</tmn>
<sky>2</sky>
<pty>0</pty>
```

and I need a number in the last line; 'pty'

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: hwat is the expected size of the xml, do you expect it to be always valid ?  do you really NEED lib xml if it is only for one node ? could not you scan the input only to locate the occurrences of `<pty>x</pty>`  ?

Comment: I'm reciviving it from the government using cron.

Comment: Your XML code formatting is not correct. (Do test by xmllint)

Comment: It's just a part of it :)

Comment: So, 
No way of substantially answer.

Comment: @InkyuLee so do you need libxml to parse it ? couldn't you use [strstr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) to get the tag

Comment: Is it possible to use strstr on XML file? Could you explain how to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you might not need libXML just to extract a few value, and as long as you don't care about the validity of your input, you could load the file in memory ( or part of it ).

```
char* xmlChunk; // your data will be stored inside
char* tagStartBegin = strstr(xmlChunk,"<pty");
char* tagStartEnd = strstr(tagStartBegin,">");
char* value = tagStartEnd+1;
// get the end tag
char* tagEndBegin = strstr(tagStartEnd,"</pty>");
//end the string here
*tagEndBegin = '\0';
// parse your value
doSomeThing(value);
```

You might need to adapt your code for unicode input if any